# Concatenate two JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have two JSON objects with the same structure and I want to concat them together using Javascript. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: How exactly do you want to concat them? Each element of both objects or both objects as a new object having the origin objects as elements or …?

Comment: Basically I have an array of 10 Json objects. I then make an Ajax call to get another 10 Json objects and I want to concat them together to create an array of 20 objects.

Comment: Do you have JSON _objects_ (deserialized into a variable of type Object) or _strings_ (serialized form)?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Based on your description in the comments, you'd simply do an array concat:

```
var jsonArray1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}, {'name': "dofug", 'id':23}];
var jsonArray2 = [{'name': "goud", 'id':1}, {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52}];
jsonArray1 = jsonArray1.concat(jsonArray2);
// jsonArray1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}, {'name': "dofug", 'id':23}, 
//{'name': "goud", 'id':1}, {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52}];
```

Comment: Your assumption about the value of jsonArray1 is incorrect. concat doesn't modify the original array, it returns a new array.

Comment: You'd need to do jsonArray1 = jsonArray1.concat(jsonArray2);

Comment: For the 1, 2, 3 this can be handy for a clean merge: `var arr3 = [].concat(arr1, arr2);`

Answer (score 51):

The actual way is using JS Object.assign.

```
Object.assign(target, ...sources)
```

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

There is another object spread operator which is proposed for ES7 and can be used with Babel plugins.

```
 Obj = {...sourceObj1, ...sourceObj2}
```

Answer (score 46):

If you'd rather copy the properties:

```
var json1 = { value1: '1', value2: '2' };
var json2 = { value2: '4', value3: '3' };


function jsonConcat(o1, o2) {
 for (var key in o2) {
  o1[key] = o2[key];
 }
 return o1;
}

var output = {};
output = jsonConcat(output, json1);
output = jsonConcat(output, json2);
```

Output of above code is`{ value1: '1', value2: '4', value3: '3' }`

Comment: As they are objects, you don't need to return it, as objects are passed by reference

Comment: Had an interesting corner case where I needed to merge properties from two JSON objects, this worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 40):

I use:

```
let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

let y = {c: 4, d: 5, e: 6 }

let z = Object.assign(x, y)

console.log(z)

// OUTPUTS:
{ a:1, b:2, c:4, d:5, e:6 }
```

From [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-add-two-JSON-objects-into-one-object-JavaScript).

Answer (score 27):

You can use jquery [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method.

Example:

```
o1 = {"foo":"bar", "data":{"id":"1"}};
o2 = {"x":"y"};
sum = $.extend(o1, o2);
```

Result:

```
sum = {"foo":"bar", "data":{"id":"1"}, "x":"y"}
```

Comment: Better solution

Comment: Simpler and cleaner solution.

Comment: A case where jQuery _isn't_ overkill.

Answer (score 18):

One solution is to use a list/array:

```
var first_json = {"name":"joe", "age":27};
var second_json = {"name":"james", "age":32};

var jsons = new Array();
jsons.push(first_json);
jsons.push(second_json);
```

**Result**

```
jsons = [
    {"name":"joe", "age":27},
    {"name":"james", "age":32}
]
```

Comment: Cough, what about `[first_json, second_json]`?

Comment: That's certainly correct if the OP has has only two objects, but since they specifically mentioned concatenation, it seemed more likely this was a contrived example looking for a way to append.

Answer (score 18):

if using TypeScript, you can use the spread operator (`...`)

```
var json = {...json1,...json2}
```

Comment: Thank you!, for some reason, this have worked better on react, to use with render states

Answer (score 12):

You can use **Object.assign()** method. The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
var o1 = { a: 1 }, o2 = { b: 2 }, o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Comment: Best, concise code with a relevant example so far! It would be nice if you clarify what happens when the keys are not unique across different objects :)

Comment: if ```o1, o2```, contains the same keys, the right one is assigned to the obj.
```JSON.stringify(Object.assign({ "test": 1 }, { "test": 2 }, { "test": 3 }, { "test2": 4 } )); => '{"test":3,"test2":4}'```

Answer (score 5):

okay, you can do this in one line of code. you'll need json2.js for this (you probably already have.). the two json objects here are unparsed strings.

```
json1 = '[{"foo":"bar"},{"bar":"foo"},{"name":"craig"}]';

json2 = '[{"foo":"baz"},{"bar":"fob"},{"name":"george"}]';

concattedjson = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json1).concat(JSON.parse(json2)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this, using underscore

```
var json1 = [{ value1: '1', value2: '2' },{ value1: '3', value2: '4' }];
var json2 = [{ value3: 'a', value4: 'b' },{ value3: 'c', value4: 'd' }];
var resultArray = [];
json1.forEach(function(obj, index){
  resultArray.push(_.extend(obj,  json2[index]));
});

console.log("Result Array", resultArray);
```

Result

Answer (score 1):

```
var baseArrayOfJsonObjects = [{},{}];
for (var i=0; i<arrayOfJsonObjectsFromAjax.length; i++) {
    baseArrayOfJsonObjects.push(arrayOfJsonObjectsFromAjax[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
let jsonFile = {};    
let schemaJson = {};    
schemaJson["properties"] = {};    
schemaJson["properties"]["key"] = "value";
jsonFile.concat(schemaJson);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way :

```
const json1 = { value1: '1', value2: '2' };
const json2 = { value2: '4', value3: '3' };

const combinedData = {
  json1,
  json2
};

console.log(combinedData)
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you want this:

U can use this for create from arrays, all arrays need contains the same number of elments.

Example:
If you have:

```
let a = ["a", "b", "c"];
let b = [1, 2, 3];
```

Use

```
concatArraysLikeJson([a, b]);
```

The result of is:

```
let result = {
 0 : ["a", 1],
 1 : ["b", 2],
 2 : ["c", 3]
};
```

**Typescript**

```
concatArraysLikeJson(arrays:any){
 let result:any = {};

 let size:number = 0;
 let make:boolean = true;

 if(arrays.length > 0){
  size = arrays[0].length;

  for(let i = 1; i < arrays.length; i++){
    let array = arrays[i];
    
    if(make){
      if(array.length != size){
        make = false;
      }
    }
  }
 }

 if(make){
  for (let o = 0; o < size; o++) {
    result[o] = [];
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
    const array = arrays[i];

    //console.log(array);

    for (let o = 0; o < size; o++) {
      const element = array[o];
      result[o].push(element);
    }
  }

  return result;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
concatArraysLikeJson(arrays){
 let result = {};

 let size = 0;
 let make = true;

 if(arrays.length > 0){
  size = arrays[0].length;

  for(let i = 1; i < arrays.length; i++){
    let array = arrays[i];
    
    if(make){
      if(array.length != size){
        make = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

if(make){
  for (let o = 0; o < size; o++) {
    result[o] = [];
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
    const array = arrays[i];

    //console.log(array);

    for (let o = 0; o < size; o++) {
      const element = array[o];
      result[o].push(element);
    }
  }

  return result;
}else{
  return false;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON Objects and Arrays can be combined in multiple ways within a structure

I can merge json with rules using [json-object-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-object-merge)

```js
import JSONObjectMerge from "json-object-merge";

const target = {
  store: {
    book: [
      {
        category: "reference",
        author: "Nigel Rees",
        title: "Sayings of the Century",
        price: 8.95
      }
    ],
    bicycle: {
      color: "red",
      price: 19.95
    }
  }
};

const source = {
  store: {
    book: [
      {
        category: "fiction",
        author: "Evelyn Waugh",
        title: "Sword of Honour",
        isbn: "0-679-43136-5",
        price: 12.99
      }
    ]
  }
};
const merged = JSONObjectMerge(target, source, { "$.store.book": "PREPEND" });

expect(merged).toEqual({
  store: {
    book: [
      {
        // books from source are prepended to the original array
        category: "fiction",
        author: "Evelyn Waugh",
        title: "Sword of Honour",
        isbn: "0-679-43136-5",
        price: 12.99
      },
      {
        category: "reference",
        author: "Nigel Rees",
        title: "Sayings of the Century",
        price: 8.95
      }
    ],
    bicycle: {
      color: "red",
      price: 19.95
    }
  }
});
```