# Concatenate two json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

is there any way to Aggregation two json object together and assign the result to the first object
i have tow Json object and i want to Aggregation  them into one object

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function () {

                    var FirstObject= [
                    { "label": "salem", "actor": "" },
                { "label": "Aragorn", "actor": "Viggo Mortensen" },
                { "label": "Arwen", "actor": "Liv Tyler" },
                { "label": "Bilbo Baggins", "actor": "Ian Holm" },
                { "label": "Boromir", "actor": "Sean Bean" },
                { "label": "Frodo Baggins", "actor": "Elijah Wood" },
            { "label": "Gandalf", "actor": "Ian McKellen" },
                { "label": "Gimli", "actor": "John Rhys-Davies" },
                { "label": "Gollum", "actor": "Andy Serkis" },
            { "label": "Legolas", "actor": "Orlando Bloom" },
                { "label": "Meriadoc Merry Brandybuck", "actor": "Dominic Monaghan" },
                { "label": "Peregrin Pippin Took", "actor": "Billy Boyd" },
         { "label": "Samwise Gamgee", "actor": "Sean Astin" }
                ];
        $("#search").keyup(function () {


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "WebService1.asmx/GetDocumentNames",
                data: '{ }',
                success: function (data) { 
                     **FirstObject =data.d**




                },
                error: function () { aler("Salem Error"); }
            }

   );
        });



    });


</script>
```

so on the statement   **FirstObject =data.d**   i want the  Aggregation

Comment: Have a look at jQuery’s `extend` that merges deep objects effectively: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: "Concatenating" two objects is a confusing choice of words and I also understood he wanted to "merge" two objects, but I think he actually wants to concatenate two arrays, or add an object to an array...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concat JSON objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433627/concat-json-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jQuery extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) like this:

```
// first argument tells jQuery's extend to deep copy the properties
$.extend( true, FirstObject, data.d );
```

quote from jQuery documentation:

> Merge two objects recursively, modifying the first.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `FirstObject` is actually an array, and **assuming what you receive is not an Array but a JSON Object** to append or aggregate it to the array, you just need to call the Array's method `push`.

```
FirstObject.push(data.d);
```

If what you're receiving is a JSON Array rather that a JSON Object, you could use the `concat` method in the array.

```
FirstObject.concat(data.d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in below example:

```
var jsonArray1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}, {'name': "dofug", 'id':23}];
var jsonArray2 = [{'name': "goud", 'id':1}, {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52}];
jsonArray1 = jsonArray1.concat(jsonArray2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge the JSON objects and maintain the common keys.

```js
var object1 = {
  'key1': 10,
  'key2': 'Hello ',
  'key3': [
    'I',
    'am'
  ],
  'key4': {
    'key5': 'Hi',
    'key6': 11
  }
};
var object2 = {
  'key1': 11,
  'key2': 'World',
  'key3': [
    'an',
    'Array'
  ],
  'key4': {
    'key5': ' there',
    'key6': '#SomeRandomString'
  }
};

function isArray(value) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]';
}

function isObject(value) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]';
}

var result = {};
for (var key in object1) {
  if (object1.hasOwnProperty(key) && object2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  
  //check if the value is of type array (works for key 3)
    if (isArray(object1[key]) && isArray(object2[key])) {
      result[key] = [];
      for (var i in object1[key]) {
        result[key].push(object1[key][i])
      }
      for (var i in object2[key]) {
        result[key].push(object2[key][i])
      }
    } 
    
  //check if the value is of type object (works for key 4)
    else if (isObject(object1[key])) {
      result[key] = {};
      for (var key_inner in object1[key]) {
        if (object1[key].hasOwnProperty(key_inner) && object2[key].hasOwnProperty(key_inner)) {
          result[key][key_inner] = object1[key][key_inner] + object2[key][key_inner];
        }
      }
    } else {
      result[key] = object1[key] + object2[key];
    }
  }
}
//console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Object.assign()** method to concatenate a json object. The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
var o1 = { a: 1 }, o2 = { b: 2 }, o3 = { c: 3 };        
var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```