# Glue together two JSON files

Tags: jquery, json

I have a script that calls a [JSON file](http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/gluon-alfred-vis/alfred.json):

```
$.getJSON( 'alfred.json', function(data) {
    ...
}
```

Now I have a second file `alfred_offline.json` with the same structure.

How can I merge the second JSON string into the first with a special field in each element:

```
{offline: true}
```

so I can run them as one in the `function(data)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concat JSON objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433627/concat-json-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newArray = [];
$.getJSON( 'alfred.json', function(data) {
        newArray = data;
        var allData = newArray.concat(alfred_offline.json);
       //do something with `allData`
       }
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: data.concat is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using jQuery try this:

```
function yourCustomFunction(data){
    // here is the merged data
}

$.getJSON( 'alfred.json', function(alfredData) {
    $.getJSON( 'alfred_offline.json', function(alfredOfflineData) {
        var merged = $.extend(alfredData, alfredOfflineData);
        yourCustomFunction(merged);
    });
});
```

Will merge the objects. switching the order of those in the function you will control which data overwrites which.