# JSON .concat() function in google app script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have tried to concatenate two JSON objects in Google App Script however it always gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Funktion concat in Objekt [object Object] nicht gefunden (Zeile 53, Datei "")
```

What are the solutions for this problem? I guess the concat() function is not part of the Google App Script API.

What I am trying to do:
Read Schema.org JSON from various E-Mails and try to save this data in a .json file.

Code:

```
function extractFromGmail(subject,jsonName) {
  subject = "json";
  jsonName = "testjson";
  var rawData = "";
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:' + subject);  
  Logger.log("thread length: " + threads.length);

  var json;

  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    var message = messages[0];
    rawData += message.getRawContent();
//    Logger.log("rawData from e-mail: " + rawData);
    if(rawData.search('itemscope') > -1)  {
      if(json === null) json = this.extractMicrodata(rawData, jsonName);
      else json.concat(this.extractMicrodata(rawData, jsonName));
    }
    if(rawData.search("json") > -1) {
      if(json === undefined) {
        Logger.log("undef");

        json = this.extractJSON(rawData, jsonName);
      }
      else {
        json = JSON.stringify(json);
        Logger.log(typeof json);   
        json = JSON.parse(json);
        Logger.log(typeof json); //this part is to test that it's a json-obj
        var result = this.extractJSON(rawData, jsonName)
        json = json.concat(result);
      }
    }
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(json));
  }
```

Comment: debug it. log json contents

Comment: check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433627/concat-json-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Object.concat() method. My guess is what you really want is to create an array, and then use .push() to add objects to that array, and then stringify the entire array at once.

But your question is phrased too vaguely to be certain that's what you need.

Comment: Actually i want to concatenate 2 JSON objects in Google App Script. However it seems as if there is no such concat() function in GAS.
extractJSON gives me a JSON object back which i want to connect to the already existing json-variable, which is also a JSON object.

Comment: What do you imagine an object concatenation would look like?
if you have two objects X and Y where  X={A:2,B:3} and Y={A:3,C:4} what do you think the result of X.concat(Y) would be?

Comment: This would be the result i was thinking of: {[{A:2,B:3} {A:3,C:4}]}

Comment: then what you want is  is an array inside an object, and objects as elements of that array:

    var jsonStuff = {elements:[]};
    jsonStuff.elements.push({A:2,B:3});
    jsonStuff.elements.push({A:3,C:4});

note that `{[{A:2,B:3} {A:3,C:4}]}` as you wrote it is not a valid object, but `{elements:[{A:2,B:3} {A:3,C:4}]}` *is* a valid object.   If you don't need the encapsulating "jsonStuff" you can of course just use a simple array alone, too.