# Javascript concat is not working on JSON objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, coffeescript

I'm trying to use `.concat()` to concatenate two objects, but it returns

> tiles.concat is not a function

This is the code (angular app and coffeescript):

```
  $scope.tiles = new UI();
  $scope.tiles.loadUITiles();
  console.log($scope.tiles);

  $scope.rooms = new RoomData;
  $scope.rooms.load();

  buildSavedRoomsScope = (tiles,rooms) ->
    console.log "tiles: " + tiles + " ||| Rooms:" + rooms
    savedRooms = tiles.concat(rooms)
    i = 0
    while  i < savedRooms.length
      room = savedRooms[i]
      room.saved = !room.hasOwnProperty('saved')
      room.uid = (if room.saved then 'saved-' else 'notSaved-') + room.id
      i++
    room


  $scope.savedRooms = buildSavedRoomsScope($scope.tiles, $scope.rooms)
  console.log $scope.savedRooms
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, as it look to me just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433627/concat-json-objects)

**EDIT**

Just like in the example, my JSON data is an array of object (same structure as the example above)

Comment: What is `tiles` at that particular moment...?

Comment: tiles: [object Object] ||| Rooms:[object Object]

Comment: That don't help much. Do a `console.log tiles` to see exactly what it is.

Comment: console.log returns what i just copied in the comment above, there is already a console.log in the code, the first line in buildSavedRoomsScope function, and it returns the above

Comment: Yes, but you're casting your object to a string, which results in `[object Object]`, which doesn't tell anyone anything.

Comment: 0: object {roomName: "test 1", roomiID: 1}, 1: object {...} and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is no 'concat' method for objects, it only exists in Array.prototype.
Instead, you can use angular.extend method. See doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend