# How to use javascript to combine two sets of data, one of which is retrieved from php?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to combine the following arrays:

```
<?php
$data_a = '{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9},{"a":10,"b":11,"c":12}';
?>
<script>
array1 = [<?=$data_a?>];
var data_b = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}';
array2 = JSON.parse(data_b);
</script>
```

I've tried and not succeeded to combine them as following:

```
combined = array2.concat(array1);
```

I want the combined array to return

```
 [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9},{"a":10,"b":11,"c":12}]
```

Anyone's help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Try `array1.push(array2);`

Comment: **Use `array1.concat(data_b)`** , for more details [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433627/concat-json-objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433627/concat-json-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array1` is a `array Object`, and `array2` is a Object, in your example you want array2 into array1, see:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9},{"a":10,"b":11,"c":12}]
```

Try:

```
array1.push(array2);
```

Note, result returns:

```
[{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9},{"a":10,"b":11,"c":12},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]
```

If needs `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}` in "first index" use `Array.unshit`, try:

```
array1.unshift(array2);
```

A tip, declare variables:

```
<script>
var array1 = [<?=$data_a?>];
var data_b = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}';
var array2 = JSON.parse(data_b);

console.log(array1.push(array2));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat()` for concat these, you'd simply do an array concat:

```
array1.concat(data_b)
```

**reference : [Concat JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433627/concat-json-objects)**

Answer (score 0):

you need to try like this

```
<?php
  $data_a = '{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9},{"a":10,"b":11,"c":12}';
?>
<script>
    var array1 = '<?=$data_a?>';            //removed [] and added var
    var data_b = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}';     // removed JSON.parse
    combined = data_b.concat(array1);       // concated data_b with array1
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer gives me exactly what I asked for. Can you help me with one more thing? Now I need to turn the combined data into an array, but JSON.parse(combined) didn't do the job when I just tried.

Comment: user jQuery.makeArray(combined) to make it an array

Comment: Thank you for your geneours answer and comment. They were helpful :)

Answer (score -2):

It is actually pretty straight forward.

```
<?php
$data_a = '{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9},{"a":10,"b":11,"c":12}';
?>
<script>
var data_b = '[<?php echo $data_a;?>,{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]';
combinedArr = JSON.parse(data_b);
// combinedArr is the combined array.
</script>
```

But the downside of it is that you need to make sure your PHP data is NOT empty, else you will get parse error.