# Combine multiple GeoJSON objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, geojson

Is it possible to merge multiple GeoJSON objects using javascript built-in functions? If not, how can I do this on the fly?

I tried `geoJSON1 = geoJSON1.concat(geoJSON2)` as per suggestions for JSON (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433627/concat-json-objects)), which returns `geoJSON1.concat is not a function`. The GeoJSONs are point features and are valid GeoJSON objects.

This is probably a simple question with "no" for an answer, but I haven't been able to find a conclusive answer.

Example GeoJSONs:

```
GeoJSON1 = { "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : [
         { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : 1,
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["-119.6165333","34.35935"]},
        "properties" : { "video" : "S105SC_Tape13o.noaudio.mpg", "video_second" : "0", "time" : "19:26:58", "date" : "2005-08-26"}
        },
         { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : 2,
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["-119.6165167","34.35935"]},
        "properties" : { "video" : "S105SC_Tape13o.noaudio.mpg", "video_second" : "2", "time" : "19:27:00", "date" : "2005-08-26"}
        }
    ]
}

GeoJSON2 = { "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : [
         { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : 27,
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["-119.61635","34.3593833"]},
        "properties" : { "video" : "S105SC_Tape13o.noaudio.mpg", "video_second" : "55", "time" : "19:27:53", "date" : "2005-08-26"}
        },
         { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : 28,
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["-119.6163333","34.3594"]},
        "properties" : { "video" : "S105SC_Tape13o.noaudio.mpg", "video_second" : "56", "time" : "19:27:54", "date" : "2005-08-26"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired result (single GeoJSON with all the features of the originals):

```
newGeoJSON = { "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : [
         { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : 1,
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["-119.6165333","34.35935"]},
        "properties" : { "video" : "S105SC_Tape13o.noaudio.mpg", "video_second" : "0", "time" : "19:26:58", "date" : "2005-08-26"}
        },
         { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : 2,
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["-119.6165167","34.35935"]},
        "properties" : { "video" : "S105SC_Tape13o.noaudio.mpg", "video_second" : "2", "time" : "19:27:00", "date" : "2005-08-26"}
        },
         { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : 27,
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["-119.61635","34.3593833"]},
        "properties" : { "video" : "S105SC_Tape13o.noaudio.mpg", "video_second" : "55", "time" : "19:27:53", "date" : "2005-08-26"}
        },
         { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : 28,
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["-119.6163333","34.3594"]},
        "properties" : { "video" : "S105SC_Tape13o.noaudio.mpg", "video_second" : "56", "time" : "19:27:54", "date" : "2005-08-26"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Glancing at http://geojson.org/ suggests you have **objects** not **arrays**.

Comment: Could you add some examples of what the input looks like and what the desired output looks like?

Comment: @Quentin Is that why the `concat` method doesn't work? @kristaps I added some simple examples of input and result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use array expansion syntax (the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...`).

```
// Given GeoJSON1 GeoJSON2

var newGeoJSON = { 
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [... GeoJSON1.features, ... GeoJSON2.features]
}
```

This can generalize as a function:

```
function concatGeoJSON(g1, g2){
    return { 
        "type" : "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [... g1.features, ... g2.features]
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the array `concat` method, since the GeoJSON features field is an array:

```
function concatGeoJSON(g1, g2){
    return { 
        "type" : "FeatureCollection",
        "features": g1.features.concat(g2.features)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function. In your case, here's what you would do.

```
var GeoJSON1 = { 'bat': 'baz'}

var GeoJSON2 = { 'foo':'bar'}

var both = {};

Object.assign(both, GeoJSON1, GeoJSON2);
console.log(both);
// Object {bat: 'baz', foo:'bar'}
```

Comment: That does work with your example, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to combine the GeoJSON objects, it only returns the last object (in this case GeoJSON2). Must be due to the structure of GeoJSONs? Thanks for showing me a new function though.