# Merging two json arrays (loaded into memory) into one json array

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I have two json array, which i have initialised as given below.

```
local=[{"account_id":"01C","id":"0XVWKCFV6P9CA5"},{"account_id":"CSDTHQ","id":"631QGYBNSF"},...............]

org=[{"account_id":"BJPKWSH","id":"15BS0XP4F91V6YH4G0PV"},{"account_id":"01BKK44V5F6A1FKH60Q0ANX9JX","id":"01BKK44V7"},.....................]
```

what i want is something like below.

```
outputJson=[{"account_id":"BJPKWSH","id":"15BS0XP4F91V6YH4G0PV"},
{"account_id":"BJPKWSH","id":"15BS0XP4F91V6YH4G0PV"},
{"account_id":"01BKK44V5F6A1FKH60Q0ANX9JX","id":"01BKK44V7"},.....................]
```

i.e. i want to merge these two json arrays into one.
I tried this,

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' <<< "$local $org"
```

but it is giving `parse error: Invalid literal at line 1, column 17`

Comment: single quote the variable content?

Comment: above variable is what i am getting as a sql query output, does not sound feasible to me to make single quote these items.

Comment: If you're storing the sql results in a variable, use process substitution to directly feed the results into jq like `< <(sqlite first query ; sqlite second query)`

Comment: sjsam,
single quote also does not seem to work,
used this.
```sed "s/\"/'/g" <<< "$local" > local```
```sed "s/\"/'/g" <<< "$org" > org```

Comment: If you have initialised those variables like `local=[{"account_id":...` all those double quotes are gone. You need to enclose json value in single quotes wile assigning them to variables, e.g `local='[{"account_id":...'`

Comment: oguz, realised my mistake. quoting the json in a single quote fixed the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate two JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433627/608639), [Merge two json/javascript arrays in to one array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10384845/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `+`, not `*`:

```
#!/bin/sh

j1='[{"account_id":"01C","id":"0XVWKCFV6P9CA5"},{"account_id":"CSDTHQ","id":"631QGYBNSF"}]'
j2='[{"account_id":"BJPKWSH","id":"15BS0XP4F91V6YH4G0PV"},{"account_id":"01BKK44V5F6A1FKH60Q0ANX9JX","id":"01BKK44V7"}]'
echo $(jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' <<EOF
$j1
$j2
EOF
)
```

produces:

```
[ { "account_id": "01C", "id": "0XVWKCFV6P9CA5" }, { "account_id": "CSDTHQ", "id": "631QGYBNSF" }, { "account_id": "BJPKWSH", "id": "15BS0XP4F91V6YH4G0PV" }, { "account_id": "01BKK44V5F6A1FKH60Q0ANX9JX", "id": "01BKK44V7" } ]
```

Comment: your bracket is misplaced in ```echo``` statement?
i used this, ``` echo $(jq -s '.[0] + .[1]') <<EOF ```
```$j1```
```$j2```
```EOF```
and it's stuck waiting for the input.

Comment: @RajivRai Nothing is misplaced, nor does it hang. Just copy and paste the entire script into a file and run it to see.

Comment: executed exactly what you have given here and it is throwing error.
./test.bash: line 20: warning: here-document at line 20 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./test.bash: line 19: warning: here-document at line 19 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
null
./test.bash: line 20: [{"account_id":"01C","id":"0XVWKCFV6P9CA5"},{"account_id":"CSDTHQ","id":"631QGYBNSF"}]: command not found
./test.bash: line 21: [{"account_id":"BJPKWSH","id":"15BS0XP4F91V6YH4G0PV"},{"account_id":"01BKK44V5F6A1FKH60Q0ANX9JX","id":"01BKK44V7"}]: command not found
./test.bash: line 22: EOF: command not found

Comment: @RajivRai Please stop trying to put chunks of code or error messages or anything else split up by lines in a comment. It doesn't work.

Comment: @RajivRai If you're getting an error on line 22, you didn't copy and paste the script in my answer because it doesn't have that many lines.

Comment: @RajivRai Fixed to work with bash. (I was testing with dash, which accepts the original version, though with more testing bash, zsh and ksh93 didn't. My bad.)

Comment: Thanks Shawn, even what i was trying earlier is working now but after quoting the json into single course(' ') just like you did. I think i was initialising the variable  incorrectly. Your solution is also working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you need. If you need to just merge the two arrays into one, you can use

```
jq '[.[0][], .[1][]]' <<< "[$local, $org]"
```