# node.js append json to a JSON file that is not using array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to append data to a JSON file that **is not using an array** using FS.
The file needs to look something like this:

```
{
    "roll.705479898579337276.welcomemessage": "There is a welcome message here",
    "roll.726740361279438902.welcomemessage": "This is a welcome message for a different server"
}
```

I have managed to get it to write the first bit, but it ends the file, and using fs.appendFile would cause this:

```
{
    "roll.705479898579337276.welcomemessage": "There is a welcome message here"
}
{
    "roll.726740361279438902.welcomemessage": "This is a welcome message for a different server"
}
```

which causes an EOF error. The file needs to be layed out like the top example, since I need to access it in a particular way.

This code:

```
fs.readFile('welcomemessages.json', function (err, readData) {
        var json = JSON.parse(readData);
        json.push(dataToWrite);
        fs.writeFile('welcomemessages.json', JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    })
```

works, if the JSON file is set as an array, but then I can't interact with it like I need to. This is driving me completely crazy as I have been doing this for about two weeks solid, and I am EXTREMELY tired of having every link on google either: not work, or do something that I don't want to do AT ALL. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/433673/9715163 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fs.readFile('welcomemessages.json', function (err, readData) {
        var json = JSON.parse(readData);
        for (let property in dataToWrite) {
            json[property] = dataToWrite[property];
        }
        fs.writeFile('welcomemessages.json', JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    })
```

The code above assumes your file is saved as a JSON Object instead of an array. Then it traverses the properties of the dataToWrite object and copies them to the json object, which should be saved in the format you're looking for. Notice the way I traverse the properties of the dataToWrite object, that means `anObject.aProp === anObject["aProp"]`.